# Run mqtt broker on greengrass core AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-core

I am currently running AWS greengrass core in ubuntu container which is running perfectly fine. What I want is to send data to AWS IOT using core mqtt broker. What I have read till now is greengrass core has its own MQTT broker which can be configured. For this I tried to update the deployment as mentioned in this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/configure-greengrass-core-v2.html

But still I cannot see mqtt broker coming up. I have one more container which is sending data to some other mqtt broker and I want to send that same data to AWS IoT core. For that I need to configure in the application the mqtt broker running on AWS greengrass core.

Again I have two questions:

1. Whether the approach that I am taking is correct or not? Can we configure mqtt broker to run locally on AWS greengrass core. If yes then how can we do it ?
2. If we cannot run mqtt broker on AWS greengrass , then what is the way we can send data to IoT core. Can we achieve it by creating some custom component like lambda function ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently trying to set up this local MQTT broker as well but I don't find a lot of information.. Except the Greengrass v2 workshop (https://greengrassv2.workshop.aws/en/chapter7_mqtt_broker.html) but it ain't working for me.
For your 2nd question, if you are running greengrass v2, then I'd recommand you to deploy components (recipes + artifacts) instead of lambda functions.
In order to send data from your Greengrass Device to your AWS IoT Core, then you need to create the appropriate recipes, the appropriate artifacts.
I could show you an example if you want.
Shann,

Answer (score 2):

For Greengrass v2, If you have **aws.greengrass.Nucleus** component installed in your IOT core device you can using packages mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/interprocess-communication.html#ipc-requirements to send MQTT message from core device to IOT Core (Nodejs is currently not supported)

**example can be found in**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/ipc-iot-core-mqtt.html

**IOT Core Data Endpoint**
If you have [Greengrass CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/greengrass-cli-component.html) component installed on Greengrass core device
you can run

```
sudo /greengrass/v2/bin/greengrass-cli component list
```

and find the iotDataEndpoint and mqtt configuration under aws.greengrass.Nucleus

```
Component Name: aws.greengrass.Nucleus
Version: 2.3.0
State: FINISHED
Configuration: {... "iotDataEndpoint":"xyz-ats.iot.region.amazonaws.com", "mqtt":{"spooler":{}},...}
```